# Is it possible to add different types to a single arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, sentinel

I need to create an ArrayList (well it doesn't have to be an ArrayList but that's what I'm attempting so far) to hold student ids, marks, and course names.
I have something like this so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MarksHandling {
  static Scanner keybrd = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main (String[]args){
    ArrayList<String> studentsCourses= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList marks= new ArrayList();

while (keybrd.next()!="-1"|| keybrd.nextInt()!=-1){
  System.out.println("Please Type Your ID Number (-1 to quit)\n");
  studentsCourses.add(keybrd.next());
  System.out.println("Please Type Your Course Name (-1 to quit)\n");
  studentsCourses.add(keybrd.next());
  System.out.println("Please Type Your Mark (-1 to quit)\n");
  marks.add(keybrd.nextInt());
    }
  System.out.println("Done");

  }
}
```

(Mind the indentation; it tends to be messed up when I paste in from my IDE)
I understand that I could just enter all of them as strings and it would be find; but in the end I need to find which student has the highest grade and in which course...

So I thought of trying two different arrays (One for Strings and one for Int)
but that caused issues with my sentinel (Which I am currently trying to fix..)

Is there a way to accept both "int" and "String" types into the same arrayList and access them as such?

Comment: Yes it is possible if you use `ArrayList<Object>`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Why don't you use `ArrayList<Student>` and create a `Student` class with a `int id`, `String name` and `int mark`?

Comment: Instead `ArrayList`, you can use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: heh another student marks question... which school gave this assignment today?

Comment: @IswantoSan - how will he use a `HashMap`? **Id+Course+Marks** is his requirement.

Comment: @SimonArsenault Sorry; could you expand slightly? (I'm really new to Java)

Comment: @R.J: sorry i miss it

Comment: @OscarWilde: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Comment: @Gus Yeah, exactly... annoying. I guess it gets the point across for what we're learning but you'd think there would be something different to try... students can't all hand in the same answers but teachers can all hand out the same questions...

Comment: Sounds like you're new to Object Oriented Programming...

Comment: @SimonArsenault Sorry my reply was rather vague; I understand the class part of your response but your saying to create a class that has the properties of each student inputted and then assign the classes to an array...?

Comment: @OscarWilde - Exactly!

Comment: @MouseEvent Indeed I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way to do this in a OO language is to create a `Student` class with  `id`, `marks`, and `course names` as member variables of this class, and to use

```
ArrayList<Student> studentsCourses= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Comment: This is good advice but it assumes his course has covered the use of fields and instance methods in objects already.

Comment: @Gus So, do you think I should give him the `Student` class design?? :)

Comment: It hasn't really; but I think I understand the basic premise of what he is suggesting... 
Essentially then each index of the arrayList would hold 3 properties (the state) of each student (mark,id,course)?

And any call of said index would then provide all 3 results? Or am I way off base here?

Comment: @OscarWilde Any call of said index would return a `Student` object which has 3 properties(mark,id,course).

Comment: @codeMan Okay, that makes sense; but then how would I input a random number of students? (Hence the sentinel) there could be 20 students or 1 students depending on how many the user wants to input; is there a way to create a new object each time through a for loop or something? Because I couldn't manually create the objects ahead of time.

Comment: yeah, you can do this: Student s= null; while(/*some condition*/){s= new Student(); /*readID from keyboard*/ s.setId(id); /*read marks*/ s.setMarks(marks) /* read cources*/ s.setCourses(courses); studentsCourses.add(s);//adding the object to arraylist }

Comment: @codeMan fantastic! Thank you for all your time! Really really helpful!